# how to remove percentage from tooltip from AmChart.React pie chart

Tags: reactjs, amcharts

i'm using amchart with react it works well with all things but i have a problem i don't want to show percentage on tool tip

[image]

here i want to show only Plavix : 457 not percentage

```
 <AmCharts.React
        style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "500px",
            marginTop: "-20px"
        }}
        options={{
            "type": "pie",
            "labelRadius": -35,
            "labelText": "[[count]]",
            "titles": titles,
            "theme": "light",
            "growSlices": true,
            "innerRadius": "0%",
            "dataProvider": reqData,
            "valueField": "count",
            "titleField": "name",
            "colorField": "color"
        }}/>
```

here is my code

Answer (score 0):

did it just by adding balloonText property

```
<AmCharts.React
    style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "500px",
        marginTop: "-20px"
    }}
    options={{
        "type": "pie",
        "labelRadius": -35,
        "labelText": "[[count]]",
        "titles": titles,
        "theme": "light",
        "growSlices": true,
        "innerRadius": "0%",
        "dataProvider": reqData,
        "valueField": "count",
        "titleField": "name",
        "colorField": "color",
        "balloonText": "[[name]]: [[count]]"
    }}/>
```

"balloonText": "any string you want"